# change Label position at runtime

Tags: iphone

How to change `UILabel` position at runtime ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
label.frame = CGRectMake(...);
```

or

```
label.center = CGPointMake(...);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
label.frame = CGRectMake(newX, newY, label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height);
```

You can also change width and height if needed.