# Can you establish a button in IB and move it programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a button set up in IB.  I have an IBOutlet set up and the onscreen object linked to it.  Is there a way to programmatically change that buttons position and/or size?  I know you can change the title and some things but I don't see how to change it's position or size.

Thank You.

Comment: check similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758224/change-label-position-at-runtime/3758242

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can change the [`frame`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame) of the button (or any UIView).

```
CGRect frame = [button frame];
frame.origin.x += 100;  // change the location
frame.size.width += 100;  // change the size
[button setFrame:frame];
```

Comment: Thank you sirs.  I believe you've provided me the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You simply create a new frame for it i.e. `myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,123,412);` and it moves to that new frame.  The order for CGRectMake is (origin x, origin y, width, height).